# Code Golf: Ulam Spiral

Tags: language-agnostic, code-golf, rosetta-stone

### The Challenge

The shortest code by character count to output [Ulam's spiral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_spiral) with a spiral size given by user input.

Ulam's spiral is one method to map prime numbers. The spiral starts from the number 1 being in the center (1 is not a prime) and generating a spiral around it, marking all prime numbers as the character '`*`'. A non prime will be printed as a space ' '.

[alt text http://liranuna.com/junk/ulam.gif](http://liranuna.com/junk/ulam.gif)

### Test cases

```
Input:
    2
Output:
    * *
      *
    *  
    
Input:
    3
Output:
    *   *
     * * 
    *  **
     *   
      *  
      
Input:
    5
Output:
        * *  
     *     * 
    * *   *  
       * * * 
      *  ** *
     * *     
    *   *    
     *   *   
    *     *
```

Code count includes input/output (i.e full program).

Comment: I am sorry in advanced if this seems biased toward a certain group of languages - this is not by design. Also, Happy thanks giving!

Comment: I was expecting a turkey-printing golf.  =[

Comment: Arrgh..I guess it's time to learn J. Is it acceptable to have an upper bound for the input/grid size, say 99 or whatever?

Comment: good grief ... one of the weirdest code golf challenges yet.

Comment: @gnibbler: it's code golf! also, I didn't really mean J as a favorable language, I said a set of languages. I won't reveal more.

Comment: Forget about an honest J answer: here's a cheat sheet: http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/play132.htm

Comment: If a language comes with a prime testing function, can we use it or do we have to write our own?

Comment: And, no matter how i contort my thinking, i cannot figure out how example 1 is a spiral. Can even numbers be exempted on the grounds that it's a lot tougher to handle them?

Comment: RCIX: Did you read the wikipedia article? Ulam's spiral is a way to visualize prime numbers. If you want more info, visit http://www.numberspiral.com/. There is no need to downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote, just a confused golfer asking a couple of questions :)

Comment: mainly confused about how to structure my output in a spiral, but working on it

Comment: RCIX: Sorry then, a downvote accord seconds after your comment, I assumed it was you. Sorry for the wrong assumption. Regarding even numbers, they do not cause any special case. Input is number of spiral loops, not width of the square. As for the structure, that's what the image, and the wikipedia page are for.

Comment: Yeow. Your code golfs are certainly intriguing, and challenging, but this is a little too challenging for my taste. I'll keep tuned to this channel though! :D

Comment: I like the dancing figure with input 5.  Is it just me or is it my browser? (Or a runner at the start)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Golfscript - 92 Characters

~.(:S+,:R{S\-:|;R{S-:$|>' *'1/[|$.|]2/@:d|~)$<!^=~:$;:y.*4*$-y-)2d*$y-*+:$,{)$\%!},,2==}%n}%

**97 characters**
~.(:S+,:R{S\-:|;R{S-:$|>' *'1/[|$.|]2/@:d|~)$<!^=~:$;:y.*4*$-y-)2d*$y-*+.1=3*+:$,2>{$\%!},!=}%n}%

**99 characters**
~.(:S+,{S-}%:R{~):|;R{:$|>' *'1/[|$.|]2/@:d|~)$<!^=~:$;:y.*4*$-y-)2d*$y-*+.1=3*+:$,2>{$\%!},!=}%n}%

**100 characters**
~:S.(+,{S(-}%:R{~):|;R{:$|>' *'1/[|$.|]2/@:d|~)$<!^=~:$;:y.*4*$-y-)2d*$y-*+.1=3*+:$,2>{$\%!},!=}%n}%

**101 characters**
    ~:S.(+,{S(-}%:R{~):v;R{:$v>:d;' *'1/[v$.v]2/v~)$<!d^=~:$;:y.*4*$-y-)2d*$y-*+.1=3*+:$,2>{$\%!},!=}%n}%

Comment: +1 I don't really speak golfscript, but the algorithm looks familiar

Comment: @drhirsch: Yes, I think your formula for directly calculating the value at each location is very clever :)

Answer (score 28):

## Python - 203 Characters

```
  _________________________________________________________
 /x=input();y=x-1;w=x+y;A=[];R=range;k,j,s,t=R(4)          \
| for i in R(2,w*w):                                        |
|  A+=[(x,y)]*all(i%d for d in R(2,i))                      |
|  if i==s:j,k,s,t=k,-j,s+t/2,t+1                           |
|  x+=j;y+=k                                                | 
| for y in R(w):print"".join(" *"[(x,y)in A]for x in R(w))  |
 \_________________________________________________________/
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||


x=input();y=x-1;w=x+y
A=[];R=range;k,j,s,t=R(4)
for i in R(2,w*w): 
 A+=[(x,y)]*all(i%d for d in R(2,i))
 if i==s:j,k=k,-j;s,t=s+t/2,t+1
 x+=j;y+=k
for y in R(w):print"".join(" *"[(x,y)in A]for x in R(w))
```

**How it works**
The idea is to fill A with x,y coords that need to be printed as '*'
The algorithm starts at the cell corresponding to 2, so the special case of testing 1 for primality is avoided.
x,y is the cell of interest
j,k keep track of whether we need to inc or dec x or y to get to the next cell
s is the value of i at the next corner
t keeps track of the increment to s

all(i%d for d in R(2,i)) does the primality check

The last line is rather clumsy. It iterates over all the cells and decides whether to place a space or an asterisk

Comment: I spent a good 10 seconds wondering if the cow actually was legal syntax

Comment: Well... looks interesting. So how does it work? (I don't have a clue of python)

Comment: @drhirsch: I added an explanation, I am still debating whether this sort of algorithm in golfscript can be shorter than the one I already have.

Answer (score 10):

**MATLAB:** <strike>182</strike> <strike>167</strike> 156 characters

Script `ulam.m`:

```
A=1;b=ones(1,4);for i=0:(input('')-2),c=b(4);b=b+i*8+(2:2:8);A=[b(2):-1:b(1);(b(2)+1:b(3)-1)' A (b(1)-1:-1:c+1)';b(3):b(4)];end;disp(char(isprime(A)*10+32))
```

And formatted a little nicer:

```
A = 1;
b = ones(1,4);
for i = 0:(input('')-2),
  c = b(4);
  b = b+i*8+(2:2:8);
  A = [b(2):-1:b(1); (b(2)+1:b(3)-1)' A (b(1)-1:-1:c+1)'; b(3):b(4)];
end;
disp(char(isprime(A)*10+32))
```

Test cases:

```
>> ulam
2
* *
  *
*  
>> ulam
3
*   *
 * * 
*  **
 *   
  *  
>> ulam
5
    * *  
 *     * 
* *   *  
   * * * 
  *  ** *
 * *     
*   *    
 *   *   
*     *
```

Comment: Where does it take input from? I'm unfamiliar with MATLAB but I see no obvious indication of 'get user input' or 'use stdin'.

Comment: It's a function, so you would call it with `u(3)`, `u(5)`, etc.

Comment: Challenge asks for a full program.

Comment: @LiraNuna: The first version *was* a full program, but I updated it to a new version anyway.

Comment: @Carl: Aww, that's not a very fun attitude. :)

Comment: @bcat: Yeah, especially since it's usually J or Perl that seems to win these. ;)

Comment: using isprime() is actually a bit unfair ;)

Comment: isprime() isn't a huge advantage only 1 char less that implementing one in golfscript and 15 chars less than the Python implementation - although those only work for numbers > 1

Answer (score 7):

## C, <strike>208</strike> <strike>206</strike> <strike>201</strike> <strike>200</strike> <strike>199</strike> <strike>196</strike> <strike>194</strike> <strike>193</strike> <strike>194</strike> <strike>193</strike> <strike>188</strike> <strike>185</strike> <strike>183</strike> <strike>180</strike> 176 Bytes

(if newlines are removed):

```
main(int u,char**b){
for(int v,x,y,S=v=**++b-48;--v>-S;putchar(10))
for(u=-S;++u<S;){
x=u;y=v;v>-u^v<u?:(x=v,y=u);
x=4*y*y-x-y+1+2*(v<u)*(x-y);
for(y=1;x%++y;);
putchar(y^x?32:42);}}
```

Compiled with

```
> gcc -std=c99 -o ulam ulam.c
```

Warning. This program is slow, because is does a trial division up to 2^31. But is does produce the required output:

```
    * *
 *     *
* *   *
   * * *
  *  ** *
 * *
*   *
 *   *
*     *
```

In nicely formatted C and with redundant #includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int u,v,x,y,d,S = atoi(argv[1]);

    /* v is the y coordinate of grid */
    for (v=S; v>=-S; --v)

        /* u is the x coordinate. The second operand (!putchar...) of the boolean or
         * is only ececuted a a end of a x line and it prints a newline (10) */
        for (u=-S; u<=S || !putchar(10); ++u) {

            /* x,y are u,v after "normalizing" the coordintes to quadrant 0
               normalizing is done with the two comparisions, swapping and and
               an additional term later */
            d = v<u;
            x=u;
            y=v;

            if (v<=-u ^ d) {
                x=v;
                y=u;
            }

            /* reuse x, x is now the number at grid (u,v) */
            x = 4*y*y -x-y+1 +2*d*(x-y);   

           /* primality test, y resused as loop variable, won't win a speed contest */
            for (y=2; y<x && x%y; ++y)
                 ;

            putchar(y!=x?' ':'*');
        }
}
```

It works by transforming the coordinates of the grid to the appropriate number and then performing the primality test, intead of drawing in a snake-like manner. The different equations for the four "quadrants" can be collapsed into one with swapping x and y and an additional term for "backward counting".

Comment: The primality test in the compacted version doesn't work with gcc 4.3.3. You can use y^x in the final ternary to get the char back.

Comment: I just tested it with 4.3.4 and 4.4.2, both do work. Can you specify what the problem is? And thanks for the xor-tip ;-)

Comment: For 3-9, I think this is one off. ./a.out "2" shows the proper output for three. Two doesn't work, nor do double-digit numbers.

Comment: http://ulam.pastebin.com/m5065ca86 I guess the x%y is getting calculated with the wrong value of y. Also seems to have the out-by one problem noted by ACoolie

Comment: Thanks @gnibbler and @ACoolie. For the one-off-error, I did actually reintroduce a fixed bug again. And the preincrement in the modulus does acutually __not__ work, I simply didn't check the output exactly.

Comment: Double digits don't work by design. This is the effect of the very cheap atoi() I implemented. Since in the challenge only single numbers are tested and no upper limit is given, I thought this is ok ;-) If you don't like it, add another 2 chars for a "real" atoi().

Comment: I just checked the documentation, because the "&&" is a sequence point, the post decrement in the primality test is ok and not relying on undefined behaviour. Should be ok with every compiler now ;-)

Comment: I actually copied the wrong output in the answer and always compared to it. Embarassing ^^

Comment: rather hacky, but if you start with `main(u,b){` and use `**++(char**)b-48` you can shave off some more characters (should compile with `-arch i386` since it casts an int to a pointer)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunatly the compiler won't let me increment b even after the cast (error: "lvalue required"). But of course i can omit the return type. And I used your increment, because it is so much more visual appealing than those brackets ;-)

Comment: I have another Python attempt which is tied with this one at 176 at the moment :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805796/code-golf-ulam-spiral/1812415#1812415

Comment: It's pedantic, but its 176 *chars* not 176 *bytes*

Comment: Yes, and it's really zero. With this primality test I may actually be close to the lower char limit, but you'll never know ;-)

Answer (score 5):

#### Ruby 1.8.7, 194 chars

```
n=2*gets.to_i-1
r=n**2
l,c=[nil]*r,r/2
r.times{|i|l[c]=i+1;c=i==0||l[c-n]&&!l[c+1]?c+1:l[c-1]&&!l[c-n]?c-n:l[c+n]?c-1:c+n}
r.times{|i|print"1"*l[i]!~/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/?'*':' ',i%n==n-1?"\n":''}
```

For some reason, ruby1.9 wants another space on line 4:

```
r.times{|i|l[c]=i+1;c=i==0||l[c-n]&&!l[c+1]?c+1:l[c-1]&&!l[c-n]?c-n :l[c+n]?c-1:c+n}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Python - 171

drhirsch's C ported to python.

```
S=input();R=range(-S+1,S)
for w in R:
 p="";v=-w
 for u in R:d=v<u;x,y=[(u,v),(v,u)][(w>=u)^d];x=4*y*y-x-y+1+2*d*(x-y);p+=" *"[(x>1)*all(x%f for f in range(2,x))]
 print p
```

```
echo 20 |python ulam.py 
      *     *   * *   *             *  
 *     * *     *   * *                 
*     * *                     *     *  
       * *     *   *           *     * 
                  *   * *   *          
 *               *   *       *   * *   
*     *   *           * *     *        
 *   * *     * *     *     *           
* *           *           *   *     * *
   *     *   *       *     *           
    *   *         *   * *   * * *      
 * *       *     *         * *   *     
      *     *   * *               *    
                   * *     *   *   * * 
*   *   *   * *   *       *   * *      
                   * *   *             
  *       *   * *     * * *     * * *  
   * * * * * * * *   *       *         
                  * * *           *    
             *   *  ** * * *   * * *   
      *       * * *                    
               *   *                   
    *   * *   * *   *   * *   *   * *  
 *     *   *   *     *     * *   *     
                *           *          
 *         * *     *   *   *       * * 
* *     *   *           *       *     *
   *     *     *   * *                 
              * *   *     *   *     *  
   * * * *         * *     *     * *   
      *   *           * *              
 *   * *     *     *   * *           * 
  * *       *         *       *     *  
             * *   * *         *     * 
          *   *     *     *         * *
       * *     *                 *     
*   *       *           *   *     *    
                             *     *   
*   * *   *     *           *
```

Comment: Imitation is the sincerest of flattery

Comment: @drsirsch: It's a decent advantage (in bytes) for the Python to be able build and print strings instead of having to use lists and then join with the print.

Comment: Yes, that and other nice things like the more powerful assignment operators and generally less overhead. But the Python implementation is only 9 bytes ahead. And this may even shrink further, though I am slowly running out of ideas ;-)

Answer (score 5):

#### MATLAB, 56 characters

based on [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805796/code-golf-ulam-spiral/1806793#1806793) solution, improved by using MATLAB's **spiral** function :)

```
disp(char(isprime(flipud(spiral(2*input('')-1)))*10+32))
```

**Test Cases:**

```
>> disp(char(isprime(flipud(spiral(2*input('')-1)))*10+32))
2
* *
  *
*  
>> disp(char(isprime(flipud(spiral(2*input('')-1)))*10+32))
3
*   *
 * * 
*  **
 *   
  *  
>> disp(char(isprime(flipud(spiral(2*input('')-1)))*10+32))
5
    * *  
 *     * 
* *   *  
   * * * 
  *  ** *
 * *     
*   *    
 *   *   
*     *
```

Answer (score 3):

My first code golf!

#### Ruby, <s>309</s> <s>301</s> <s>283</s> <s>271</s> 265 characters

```
s=gets.to_i;d=s*2-1;a=Array.new(d){' '*d}
e=d**2;p='*'*e;2.upto(e){|i|2.upto(e/i){|j|p[i*j-1]=' '}};p[0]=' '
s.times{|i|k=s-i-1;l=2*i;m=l+1;o=l-1
m.times{|j|n=j+k;a[k][n]=p[l**2-j];a[n][k]=p[l**2+j];a[k+l][n]=p[m**2-m+j]}
l.times{|j|a[j+k][k+l]=p[o**2+o-j]}}
puts a
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Haskell - 224 characters

```
(%)=zipWith(++)
r x=[x]
l 1=r[1]
l n=r[a,a-1..b]++(m r[a+1..]%l s%m r[b-1,b-2..])++r[d-s*2..d]where{d=(n*2-1)^2;b=d-s*6;a=d-s*4;s=n-1}
p[_]='*'
p _=' '
i n=p[x|x<-[2..n],n`mod`x==0]
m=map
main=interact$unlines.m(m i).l.read
```

i'm not the best at haskell so there is probably some more shrinkage that can occur here

output from `echo 6 | runghc ulam.hs`

```
*   *      
     * *   
* *     * *
 * *   *   
    * * *  
   *  ** * 
* * *      
 *   *     
* *   *   *
 *     *   
  *
```

---

this is a different algorithm (similar to @drhirsch's) unfortunately i cannot seem to get it below **239** characters

```
p[_]='*'
p _=' '
main=interact$unlines.u.read
i n=p[x|x<-[2..n],n`mod`x==0]
u(n+1)=map(map(i.f.o).zip[-n..n].replicate((n+1)*2-1))[n,n-1..(-n)]
f(x,y,z)=4*y*y-x-y+1+if z then 2*(x-y)else 0
o(u,v)=if(v> -u)==(v<u)then(v,u,v<u)else(u,v,v<u)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Python 2.x, <del>220C</del> <del>213C</del> <del>207C</del> <del>204C</del> <del>201C</del> <del>198C</del> <del>196C</del> 188C

Special thanks to [gnibbler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174728/gnibbler) for some hints in `#stackoverflow` on [Freenode](http://freenode.net/). Output includes a leading and trailing newline.

```
import math
v=input()*2
w=v-1
a=['\n']*w*v
p=w*v/2
for c in range(1,w*w):a[p]=' *'[(c>1)*all(c%d for d in range(2,c))];x=int(math.sqrt(c-1));p+=(-1)**x*((x*x<c<=x*x+x)*w+1)
print''.join(a)
```

(Python 3 compatibility would require extra chars; this uses [`input`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input), the [`print`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) *statement* and `/` for integer division.)

Comment: a[p]=' *'[(c>1)*all(c%d for d in r(2,c))]

Answer (score 3):

J solution: <strike>197 173 165</strike> 161 bytes (so far)
this does not use the method mentioned in the comments to the OP

```
p=:j./<.-:$g=:1$~(,])n=:<:+:".1!:1]3
d=:j.r=:1
(m=:3 :'if.y<*:n do.if.0=t=:<:t do.d=:d*0j1[t=:<.r=:r+0.5 end.m>:y[g=:y(<+.p=:p+d)}g end.')t=:2
1!:2&2(1 p:g){' *'
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby - 158 Characters

Same algorithm as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805796/code-golf-ulam-spiral/1812415#1812415), just the prime test is different

```
p=(v=(w=gets.to_i*2)-1)*w/2-1
a='
'*v*w
d=0
(v*v).times{|i|a[p]="1"*(i+1)!~/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/?42:32;d=(a[p+(z=[w,-1,-w,1])[d-1]]<32)?(d-1):d%4;p+=z[d]}
puts a
```

Answer (score 1):

**First post!** (oh wait, this isn't [SlashDot](http://slashdot.org/)?)

My entry for Team Clojure, <s>685</s> 528 characters.

```
(defn ulam[n] (let [z (atom [1 0 0 {[0 0] " "}])
m [[0 1 1 0][2 -1 0 -1][2 0 -1 0][2 0 0 1][2 0 1 0]]
p (fn [x] (if (some #(zero? (rem x %)) (range 2 x)) " " "*"))]
(doseq [r (range 1 (inc n)) q (range (count m)) [a b dx dy] [(m q)]
s (range (+ (* a r) b))]
(let [i (inc (first @z)) x (+ dx (@z 1)) y (+ dy (@z 2))]
(reset! z [i x y (assoc (last @z) [x y] (p i))])))
(doseq [y (range (- n) (inc n))] (doseq [x (range (- n) (inc n))]
(print ((last @z) [x y]))) (println))))
(ulam (dec (.nextInt (java.util.Scanner. System/in))))---

Input:
5
Output:
    * *  
 *     * 
* *   *  
   * * * 
  *  ** *
 * *     
*   *    
 *   *   
*     *
```

---

```
Input:
10
Output:
        *   * *   *
 *     *         * 
  *   * *          
         * *     * 
  * *   *       *  
         * *   *   
*   * *     * * *  
 * * * *   *       
        * * *      
   *   *  ** * * * 
    * * *          
     *   *         
*   * *   *   * *  
 *   *     *     * 
      *           *
 * *     *   *   * 
  *           *    
     *   * *       
    * *   *     *
```

Comment: You don't need to print "Input:" and "Output:" in your solution.

Comment: You should put a character count at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Not as beautiful as the previous C entry, but here's mine.

note: I'm posting because it takes a different approach than the previous one, mainly

- there's no coordinate remapping
- it gives the same results as the tests
- it works with input > 9 (two digits - no `-47` trick)

  ```
  enum directions_e { dx, up, sx, dn } direction;

  int main (int argc, char **argv) {
      int len = atoi(argv[1]);
      int offset = 2*len-1;
      int size = offset*offset;
      char *matrix = malloc(size);
      int startfrom = 2*len*(len-1);
      matrix[startfrom] = 1;
      int next = startfrom;
      int count = 1;
      int i, step = 1;
      direction = dx ;

      for (;; step++ )
          do { 
              for ( i = 0 ; i < step ; i++ ) {
                  switch ( direction ) {
                      case dx:
                          next++;
                          break;
                      case up:
                          next = next - offset;
                          break;
                      case sx:
                          next--;
                          break;
                      case dn:
                          next = next + offset;
                  }
                  int div = ++count;
                  do {
                      div--;
                  } while ( count % div );
                  if ( div > 1 ) {
                      matrix[next] = ' ';
                  }
                  else { 
                      matrix[next] = '*';
                  }
                  if (count >= size) goto dontusegoto;
              }
              direction = ++direction % 4;
          } while ( direction %2);
  dontusegoto:
      for ( i = 0 ; i < size ; i++ ) {
          putchar(matrix[i]);
          if ( !((i+1) % offset) ) putchar('\n'); 
      }
      return 0;
  }
  ```

which, adequately translated in unreadable C, becomes 339 chars.

compile with: `gcc -o ulam_compr ulam_compr.c` works on osx

`i686-apple-darwin9-gcc-4.0.1 (GCC) 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)`

and debian Lenny.

```
main(int a,char**v){
    int l=atoi(v[1]),o=2*l-1,z=o*o,n=2*l*(l-1),c=1,i,s=1,d;
    char*m=malloc(z);
    m[n]=1;
    for(;;s++)do{
            for(i=0;i<s;i++){
                if(d==0)n++;
                else if(d==1)n-=o;
                else if(d==2)n--;
                else n+=o;
                int j=++c;
                while(c%--j);
                if(j>1)m[n]=' ';else m[n]='*';
                if(c>=z)goto g;
            }d=++d%4;}while(d%2);
g:for(i=0;i<z;i++){
        putchar(m[i]);
        if(!((i+1)%o))putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Here is some output:

```
    $ ./ulam_compr 3
*   *
 * * 
* **
 *   
  *  

    $ ./ulam_compr 5
    * *  
 *     * 
* *   *  
   * * * 
  * ** *
 * *     
*   *    
 *   *   
*     *
```

Comment: +1 for showing some balls and using C. But to be honest, those two chars from using *-48 instead of atoi() wouldnt make such a big difference. But you can always discount the newlines and whitespaces, we don't need to rely on such unmanly nonsense such as intendation like those python guys.

Comment: @drhirsh: That's why so much of the Python golf ends up crammed onto the same line as the for loop :)

Comment: @drhirsch: well the difference with the -48 I think it's being made if I use more than one digit, doesn't it? I'd have to subtract it to every char given in argv[1]. 
Thanks, however, for the compliment. It was my first code golf, and I would not call myself a programmer. 
Ps: the whitespaces are at a minimum (the count was made removing all tabs and newlines). Code here shows spaces instead of tabs.

Comment: You can save two characters by leaving out the named 'a' argument (since it isn't referenced anywhere).  Also, technically none of the whitespace is required.

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 176

This one starts with a big long list of newline characters and replaces all of them except for the ones that are needed at the end of the lines.

Starting at the centre, the algorithm peeps around the lefthand corner at each step. If there is a newline character there, turn left otherwise keep going forward.

```
w=input()*2;v=w-1;a=['\n']*v*w;p=w/2*v-1;d=0;z=[w,-1,-w,1]
for i in range(v*v):a[p]=' *'[i and all((i+1)%f for f in range(2,i))];d=d%4-(a[p+z[d-1]]<' ');p+=z[d]
print"".join(a)
```

**Python - 177**
Using a string avoids "join" but ends up one byte longer since the string is immutable

```
w=input()*2;v=w-1;a='\n'*v*w;p=w/2*v-1;d=0;z=[w,-1,-w,1]
for i in range(v*v):a=a[:p]+' *'[i and all((i+1)%f for f in range(2,i))]+a[p+1:];d=d%4-(a[p+z[d-1]]<' ');p+=z[d]
print a
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python, 299 characters:**

```
from sys import *
def t(n):
 if n==1:return ' '
 for i in range(2,n):
  if n%i==0:return ' '
 return '*'
i=int(stdin.readline())
s=i*2-1
o=['\n']*(s+1)*s
c=1
g=2
d=0
p=(s+2)*(i-1)
for n in range(s**2):
 o[p]=t(n+1);p+=[1,-s-1,-1,s+1][d%4];g-=1
 if g==c:d+=1
 if g==0:d+=1;c+=1;g=2*c
print ''.join(o)
```

Comment: use `i=input()` instead of importing sys

Comment: you can also use `d+=g==c` to same some bytes

Answer (score 0):

### Lua, 302 characters

```
s=...t={" "}n=2 function p()for j=2,n-1 do if n%j==0 then n=n+1 return" "end
end n=n+1 return"*"end for i=2,s do for k=#t,1,-1 do t[k+1]=t[k]..p()end
t[1]=""for k=1,i*2-1 do t[1]=p()..t[1]end for k=2,#t do t[k]=p()..t[k]end
t[#t+1]=""for k=1,i*2-1 do t[#t]=t[#t]..p()end end print(table.concat(t,"\n"))
```

Output from `lua ulam.lua 6`:

```
*   *      
     * *   
* *     * *
 * *   *   
    * * *  
   *  ** * 
* * *      
 *   *     
* *   *   *
 *     *   
  *
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python <del>284 266 256 243 242</del> 240 char

I wanted to try recursion, I'm sure it may be heavily shortened:

```
r=range
def f(n):
 if n<2:return[[4]]
 s=2*n-1;z=s*s;c=[r(z-2*s+2,z-3*s+2,-1)];e=1
 for i in f(n-1):c+=[[c[0][0]+e]+i+[c[0][-1]-e]];e+=1
 c+=[r(z-s+1,z+1)];return c
for l in f(input()):print''.join(' *'[all(x%f for f in r(2,x))]for x in l)
```

edited under suggestion in comments

Comment: This can be golfed down to 242 at least

Comment: I shortened it a bit more, where do you think it could be shortened more?

Comment: You can use tab instead of 2 spaces for indenting. You can refactor to just have one return. Use `all(x%f for f in range(2,x))` ( there is a trick you will need to do this as it will count 1 as a prime ) instead of importing gmpy. i think rewriting the last line to use a for loop will be shorter too

Comment: Yeah very nice consideration, i'm still wondering how to use just one return and gain one more char

Comment: aaaargh it was a \n in the end of the file, argh! down to 242 now, thanks! Maybe it can be shortened even more using indexes more wisely, I'm not sure yet though.

Comment: move the 's=2'... above the if. change the if to 'if n>1'. indent the next two lines with a tab. put 'return c' on it's own line indented with a space. Now you are back to returning [[1]] so use `(x>1)*all..` to fix the prime. it's also possible to get rid of `e` altogether :) make sure you don't count the final newline of the file and you should get around 228

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica 243

```
l = Length; t = Table; f = Flatten;
h@m_ := With[{x = l@m[[1]], y = l@m}, f[{{Reverse@t[w + y + (x y), {w, x + 2}]}, 
  t[f[{(x y) + x + y + 2 + w, m[[w]], (x y) + y - w + 1}], {w, y}], 
  {t[2 + y + x + y + w + (x y), {w, x + 2}]}}, 1]];
m_~g~z_ := Nest[h, m, z] /. {_?PrimeQ -> "\[Bullet]", _Integer -> ""};
  Grid[{{1}}~g~#, Frame -> All] &
```

**Usage**

13 windings:

```
Grid[{{1}}~g~#, Frame -> All] &[13]
```

[image: Ulam]