# Is_prime function via regex in python (from perl)

Tags: python, regex, perl

I've read [this article](http://www.noulakaz.net/weblog/2007/03/18/a-regular-expression-to-check-for-prime-numbers/) where the `/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/` Perl regex is used to test if a number is prime or not.

Process:

```
s = '1' * your_number
```

If `s` matchs the regex, then it's not prime. If it doesn't, it's prime.

How would you translate that regex to Python's `re` module?

Comment: Just when I think I've seen everything...

Comment: A more compact prime test is over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1805796/code-golf-ulam-spiral `all(i%d for d in range(2,i))`

Comment: @Mike Regular-expression matching with backreferences is NP-hard: http://perl.plover.com/NPC/

Comment: See also http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=21580 and http://web.archive.org/web/20010508215502/http://www.foad.org/~abigail/Perl/Talks/Japhs/primes.html

Comment: Oh my god... that is sick, yet impressive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works as is (except without the slashes at the edges, which aren't needed in Python):

```
pattern = r'^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$'
re.match(pattern, '1'*10)    #matches
re.match(pattern, '1'*11)    #doesn't match
```

The only nonstandard regex feature needed here is backreferences (`\1`), and these are supported in both Perl and Python.

Comment: Thanks, I was having problems because I forgot the r of raw

Comment: can anyone explain why the deleted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225027/is-prime-function-via-regex-in-python-from-perl/2225069#2225069 is wrong (assuming it was deleted because it was wrong)?